# How to "reorient" an horizontal page?

Tags: pdftex

I'm using the command landscape to get horizontal orientation in my pdf document. The first page is always vertical and all the following pages are horizontal.

It works fine, however, when I print the document the first page is printed perfectly, but the horizontal ones are printed vertically with wrong resolution.

Is it possible, once I've got the doc correctly made, to reorient the horizontal pages in order to get a correct print?

Thanks you very much in advance!

A reproducible example is the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, openright, 10pt, oneside]{article}

\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{array, longtable, multirow}
\usepackage{fancyhdr, lastpage, graphicx, titling}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue, citecolor = green, filecolor = cyan]{hyperref}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\date{\today}\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{1mm}
\usepackage[hmargin=1.2cm,top=3cm,headheight=1.76cm,bottom=2cm,footskip=1cm]{geometry}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{P1}
\rhead{Pág. \thepage\ de \pageref*{LastPage}}
\lfoot{Day \today}
\cfoot{Test title}
\rfoot{Test foot}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\begin{landscape}

\lipsum

\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

If you run this code you should get my current result, however, my desired result is getting the second page rotated 90º to the left.

Comment: Using `no scale` my printer worked perfectly, assuming you want the pages to fit on the paper..

Comment: `no scale` is a latex command?

Comment: It is a printer driver option which shows up with I print the document.  Other scale options are `Fit to printable area`, `Shrink to printable area`, `Tile large pages`, `Tile all pages`, `Multiple pages per sheet` and `Booklet printing`.  I should note that I also had `Auto-rotate and center` checked.

Comment: Sorry, it was `Auto-rotate and center` that did the trick.

Comment: Ok ok, now I understand. Yes, that does the trick, but, do you think is there a way to do that directly with latex?

Comment: Use rotate instead of pdflscape?